# How to enable Datapower mapruntime option in ITX?

Tags: ibm-datapower, wtx

I am using ITX V9.0 and under properties--> transformation extender option , the mapruntime for datapower option is disabled. Could anyone let me know how to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be enabled as DataPower only supports WTX 8.4 and not ITX v9.

To my knowledge there is no set date/version for when the WTX/ITX version will be updated in Datapower.